# Is that possible to get device token using OneSignal

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

Maybe someone knows how to get device token when using OneSignal to receive notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is it:

```
OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
            @Override
            public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
                Log.d("debug", "User:" + userId);
                if (registrationId != null)
                    Log.d("debug", "registrationId:" + registrationId);

            }
        });
```

It helps to get user id and that is actually a device token.

Comment: Also one can use OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getPushToken()

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `react native` SDK you can retrieve it from the device state:

```
const pushToken = (await OneSignal.getDeviceState()).pushToken
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Flutter` use this code:

```
OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState().then((deviceState) {
     final pushToken = deviceState.pushToken;
}
```

Comment: This is depreceated

Answer (score 0):

For React Native `getDeviceState` is no longer a function on the latest OneSignal v5.0.3. Here is how you get the subscription ID and subscription token for the user after they have accepted permission:

```
const subId = OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.getPushSubscriptionId();
const subToken = OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.getPushSubscriptionToken();
```